# How a controller interacts with server in node js and angular js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to Node and Angular. I have a simple Node application where in I am rendering a table data from mssql on html page.

Here I am unable to understand how the controller gets to know that it needs to look in the server.js file for the get operation.

How routing is happening from controller to server ?

Comment: Are you taking about MEAN stack?

Comment: @muhammed yes! If I have two server.js files then how come the application understands in which file the get is available?